# corenlp package of stanford's StaggerDemo

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I wanna make a program automatically tagger the text in a directory. Here's my first step.
I made a little change to TaggerDemo.java. But it is not working properly as expected.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

class auto{

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("models/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<List<HasWord>> sentences = tagger.tokenizeText(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0])));
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : sentences) {
      ArrayList<TaggedWord> tSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
      System.out.println(Sentence.listToString(tSentence, false));
    }
  }

}
```

This is the error i got.

```
Loading default properties from trained tagger models/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger
Reading POS tagger model from models/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger ... done [2.9 sec].
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: sample-input.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at auto.main(auto.java:17)
```

Why it says file not found?

When i tried to compile it under terminal, it says edu.stanford.nlp.ling.* can not be imported...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you running the program? It seems like `sample-input.txt` is simply in a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have the file `sample-input.txt` in the current directory.

To see your current directory, use:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: thanks a lot...I just found that when using eclipse in ubuntu, /src should be added, while in Windows, just use the filename directly.